# cocos2d-x custom draw produces weird results

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have subclassed `Sprite` and in its `draw(Renderer, const kmMat4&, bool)` method, used a library that facilitates opengl shaders (not using deferred rendering as cocos itself does). I enclosed the custom calls between `glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)` and `glPopAttrib()`. I can (sometimes) see the resulting custom drawn sprite but other sprites managed by cocos are drawn in incorrect positons, with wrong colors/textures or not drawn at all. Subclassing Node did not change a thing. I have already considered CCDrawNode...
I am using v3.0 in Mac OS 10.8.x for Mac build. What do I have to do to ensure cocos gl-pipeline is not affected (and make both work as expected)?

Edit: What I am asking is; isn't it enough to use `glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)` and `glPopAttrib()`?

Comment: There's a nice XCode feature named "Capture OpenGL ES Frame" if your iOS target is alive. You can easily check difference between states before and after your custom calls.

Comment: Nice (and thanks), I may find something with that detailed/important feature of XCodes', but @see Edit.